# React-Native How to get an array from a function in the constructor of another class

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to use an array from an external function in another class.
So this function returns an array:

```
function getMarkers() {
  var markers = [];
  markers.push("example: exmple");
  return(markers);
}
```

And I want to use that array in the constructor of the class below:

```
class Home extends Component {
     constructor() {
     super();

   this.state = { getMarkers }
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In your example `getMarkers` is a function which returns an array. If you want to get that array you have to call this function:

```
const markers = getMarkers();
console.log(markers); // prints: ["example: exmple"]
this.state = { markers }
```

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @ByronSchuurman how do you use `markers`? could you share more code?